# How do I push the (underneath) container down once my "Read More" button has expanded?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, containers

I like what I've created here and the functionality / Action works to my liking. What I've had to do though, is apply a height to the red container (id="greeting")to allow the expanded text to fit nicely upon expansion. It therefore leaves an ugly amount of space below the button when I'd like the "Read More" button state to be flush against the underneath container (id="skills"). Objective: to push the #skills container down when clicking the Read More Button.

```js
var i = 0;

function read() {
  if (!i) {
    document.getElementById('more').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('dots').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('read').innerHTML = 'Read Less';
    i = 1;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('more').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('dots').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('read').innerHTML = 'Read More';
    i = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300;400&family=Open+Sans:wght@600;700&display=swap");
.container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.contact-container {
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.contact-btn {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #082449;
  color: #f7f7f5;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  border: none;
}

.contact-btn:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #082449;
  color: #082449;
  transition: ease 0.4s;
}

.btn-light {
  background-color: #f7f7f5;
  color: #082449;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  border: none;
}

.btn-light:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #f7f7f5;
  color: #f7f7f5;
  transition: ease 0.4s;
}

.btn-dark {
  background-color: #082449;
  color: #f7f7f5;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: none;
}

.btn-dark:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #082449;
  color: #082449;
  transition: ease 0.4s;
}

.t-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.lead {
  text-align: center;
}

.bottom-line {
  border: 1px solid #f43d56;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 2rem auto;
}

.py-1 {
  padding: 1rem 0rem;
}

.py-2 {
  padding: 2rem 0rem;
}

.py-3 {
  padding: 3rem 0rem;
}

.py-4 {
  padding: 4rem 0rem;
}

.my-1 {
  margin: 1rem 0rem;
}

.my-2 {
  margin: 2rem 0rem;
}

.my-3 {
  margin: 3rem 0rem;
}

.my-4 {
  margin: 4rem 0rem;
}

.items {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  background: #f43d56;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: inherit;
  opacity: 0.9;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scale(2) translateX(-75%) translateY(-75%);
  transition: transform 2s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.5, 0.4, 1);
}

.item:hover:after {
  transform: scale(2);
}

.item:hover .item-text {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.item-image {
  height: auto;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  transition: transform 2s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.5, 0.4, 1);
  display: block;
}

.item-image::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 55%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-image img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 0;
}

.item-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #f7f7f5;
  transform: translateY(-20%);
  transition: opacity 500ms cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.5, 0.4, 1), transform 500ms cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.5, 0.4, 1);
  transition-delay: 200ms;
}

.item-text-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.item-text-title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.item-text-category {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.item .item-button {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
}

.item .item-button:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #f7f7f5;
  color: #f7f7f5;
  transition: ease 0.4s;
}

#skills {
  margin: -7rem 0 0 0;
}

#skills .cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #f7f7f5;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#skills .card:first-of-type {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#skills .card {
  padding: 1rem;
}

#skills .skill-list h2 {
  color: #f43d56;
}

#skills i.fa-3x {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  color: #f43d56;
}

#skills ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#skills li {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

#skills h2 {
  padding: 1rem;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #f7f7f5;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.8;
  letter-spacing: 1.3px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #082449;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#logo {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-left: 4rem;
}

#main-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0 3rem;
  background-color: #f7f7f5;
}

#main-nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

#main-nav li {
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
}

#main-nav a {
  color: #082449;
  border: 1px solid #f43d56;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
}

#main-nav a:hover {
  background-color: #f43d56;
  color: #f7f7f5;
  transition: ease 0.4s;
}

#showcase {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  height: 60vh;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f7f7f5;
}

#showcase h1 {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

#showcase p {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

#showcase img {
  width: 100%;
}

#greeting {
  background-color: #f43d56;
  color: #f7f7f5;
  height: 70vh;
}

#greeting h1 {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  font-size: 32px;
}

#greeting p {
  margin: 1rem auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
}

#greeting #more {
  display: none;
}

#greeting .btn-light {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#contact-a h3 {
  margin-top: 10%;
}

#contact-a .text-fields {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'name email' 'subject phone' 'message message';
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  margin: 3rem 0 2rem 0;
}

#contact-a .text-fields .name-input {
  grid-area: name;
}

#contact-a .text-fields .subject-input {
  grid-area: subject;
}

#contact-a .text-fields .email-input {
  grid-area: email;
}

#contact-a .text-fields .phone-input {
  grid-area: phone;
}

#contact-a .text-fields .message-input {
  grid-area: message;
  height: 100px;
}

#contact-a .text-fields .text-input {
  padding: 0.3rem 0.6rem;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#contact-a .contact-container .btn-dark {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
}

#contact-b .contact-info {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 4rem 0;
}

#main-footer {
  background: #082449;
  color: #f7f7f5;
  height: 5rem;
}

#main-footer .footer-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  height: 5rem;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

#main-footer .social .fab {
  color: #f7f7f5;
  margin-right: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-align: center;
}

#main-footer .social .fab:hover {
  background: #f43d56;
}

@media (max-width: 1300px) {
  #showcase {
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
  }
  #greeting {
    height: 90vh;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #showcase {
    min-height: 50vh;
  }
  #showcase p {
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #showcase h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  #work-a .item-text-title {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
  #work-a .item-text-category {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }
  #greeting {
    height: 65vh;
  }
  #greeting .container {
    padding: 0 2rem;
  }
  #skills .cards {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #skills .card:first-of-type {
    border-right: none;
  }
  #skills ul {
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
}


/*===================PHONES==================================

============================================================*/

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #main-nav {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  #main-nav #logo {
    margin: 1rem 0;
  }
  #main-nav li {
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-top: 2rem;
  }
  #showcase {
    height: 85vh;
  }
  #showcase p {
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #showcase img {
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #showcase h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  #greeting {
    height: 140vh;
  }
  #greeting h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  #skills .cards {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  #skills .card:first-of-type {
    border-right: none;
  }
  #skills ul {
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
  #work-a .container {
    padding: 0 1rem;
  }
  #work-a .items {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    width: 100%;
    grid-row-gap: 0.5rem;
  }
  #work-a .items .item-image {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #work-a .items .item-text-category {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    margin-top: 1.8rem;
  }
  #work-a .items .item-text-title {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
  }
  #main-footer .footer-content {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    font-size: 0.6rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
  }
  #main-footer .social .fab {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    margin: 1rem 0;
  }
  #contact-a .text-fields {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 'name' 'email' 'phone' 'subject' 'message';
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    margin: 2rem 0;
  }
  #contact-b .contact-info {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-row-gap: 1rem;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-height: 500px) {
  #showcase {
    height: 85vh;
  }
  #showcase img {
    width: 250px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #showcase h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  #greeting {
    height: 190vh;
  }
  #greeting h1 {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
  #skills .cards {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  #skills .card:first-of-type {
    border-right: none;
  }
  #skills ul {
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
  #work-a .items {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    width: 100%;
    grid-row-gap: 1rem;
  }
  #work-a .items .item-image {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #work-a .items .item-text-title {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    margin: 0.8rem 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="greeting" class="rellax" data-rellax-speed="3">
  <div class="container" data-rellax-speed="-1">
    <h1 class="rellax" data-rellax-speed="1" data-rellax-xs-speed="0">
      Hi, I'm Jon. Nice to meet you.
    </h1>
    <p class="rellax" data-rellax-speed="1" data-rellax-xs-speed="0">
      I am a recent graduate of the Borough of Manhattan Community College where I pursued a degree in Multimedia Programming with a specialization in Frontend Web Development and Graphic Design I offer an attention to detail, analysis, and problem solving
      that will serve me well as a Frontend Developer. I enjoy working across various programs and platforms from Sketch or XD to SASS/JS/REACT and NODE to name a few. In my recent internship at Interactive One, I was able to apply this skill set in the
      development of personalized landing pages and digital marketing campaigns on sites hosted on WordPress VIP.<span id="dots">...</span
          ><span id="more">
            I also find WordPress Development to be engaging as well, especially
            theme customization and incorporating raw coding techniques to
            create a unique end product. My specialties include: Prototyping in
            Adobe XD. Building in HTML/CSS, JavaScript and React. All aspects of
            the WordPress and Squarespace platforms. I have had the chance to
            work with Firebase creating an original Blog and also the P5.js
            library creating animated projects, games and data
            visualization.</span
          >
        </p>
        <button
          type="button"
          id="read"
          class="btn-light t-center"
          onclick="read()"
        >
          Read More
        </button>
      </div>
    </section>

<!-- Section Skills -->
    <section
      id="skills"
      class="t-center py-3 rellax"
      data-rellax-xs-speed="2"
      data-rellax-speed="1.5"
      data-rellax-tablet-speed="0"
    >
      <div class="container">
        <div class="cards">
          <div class="card">
            <div>
              <i class="fas fa-code fa-3x"></i>
              <h2>Frontend Developer</h2>
              <p>
                I aim for an original, clean and streamlined approach. I
                especially enjoy coding from scratch and exploring new
                techniques.
              </p>
              <div class="skill-list">
                <h2>My Languages:</h2>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fab fa-js"></i>
                    <p>javascript</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fab fa-react"></i>
                    <p>react</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fab fa-sass"></i>
                    <p>sass</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fab fa-node"></i>
                    <p>node.js</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fas fa-database"></i>
                    <p>firebase</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fas fa-file-code"></i>
                    <p>html5 / css3</p>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>

              <div class="skill-list">
                <h2>Developer Tools:</h2>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>
                    <p>VS-Code</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fab fa-bootstrap"></i>
                    <p>Bootstrap</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fab fa-codepen"></i>
                    <p>Codepen</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
                    <p>Github</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fab fa-wordpress"></i>
                    <p>WordPress</p>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div>
              <i class="fas fa-bezier-curve fa-3x"></i>
              <h2>Graphic Design</h2>
              <p>
                I value simple content structure, clean design patterns, and
                thoughtful interactions.
              </p>
              <div class="skill-list">
                <h2>What I like to design:</h2>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fab fa-sketch"></i>
                    <p>ux / ui</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fas fa-wifi"></i>
                    <p>web</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fas fa-mobile"></i>
                    <p>mobile</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fab fa-app-store-ios"></i>
                    <p>apps</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fas fa-bezier-curve"></i>
                    <p>logos</p>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>

              <div class="skill-list">
                <h2>Design Tools:</h2>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fas fa-align-center"></i>
                    <p>Sketch</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fab fa-figma"></i>
                    <p>Figma</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fab fa-adobe"></i>
                    <p>Adobe Suite</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fas fa-drafting-compass"></i>
                    <p>Draw</p>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: seems to be the issue the margin you gave to #skills (-7rem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take off the fixed height of the #greeting and it does just that. It will expand with it's content

```js
var i = 0;

function read() {
  if (!i) {
    document.getElementById('more').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('dots').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('read').innerHTML = 'Read Less';
    i = 1;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('more').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('dots').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('read').innerHTML = 'Read More';
    i = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300;400&family=Open+Sans:wght@600;700&display=swap");
.container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.contact-container {
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.contact-btn {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #082449;
  color: #f7f7f5;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  border: none;
}

.contact-btn:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #082449;
  color: #082449;
  transition: ease 0.4s;
}

.btn-light {
  background-color: #f7f7f5;
  color: #082449;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  border: none;
}

.btn-light:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #f7f7f5;
  color: #f7f7f5;
  transition: ease 0.4s;
}

.btn-dark {
  background-color: #082449;
  color: #f7f7f5;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: none;
}

.btn-dark:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #082449;
  color: #082449;
  transition: ease 0.4s;
}

.t-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.lead {
  text-align: center;
}

.bottom-line {
  border: 1px solid #f43d56;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 2rem auto;
}

.py-1 {
  padding: 1rem 0rem;
}

.py-2 {
  padding: 2rem 0rem;
}

.py-3 {
  padding: 3rem 0rem;
}

.py-4 {
  padding: 4rem 0rem;
}

.my-1 {
  margin: 1rem 0rem;
}

.my-2 {
  margin: 2rem 0rem;
}

.my-3 {
  margin: 3rem 0rem;
}

.my-4 {
  margin: 4rem 0rem;
}

.items {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  background: #f43d56;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: inherit;
  opacity: 0.9;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scale(2) translateX(-75%) translateY(-75%);
  transition: transform 2s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.5, 0.4, 1);
}

.item:hover:after {
  transform: scale(2);
}

.item:hover .item-text {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.item-image {
  height: auto;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  transition: transform 2s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.5, 0.4, 1);
  display: block;
}

.item-image::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 55%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-image img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 0;
}

.item-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #f7f7f5;
  transform: translateY(-20%);
  transition: opacity 500ms cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.5, 0.4, 1), transform 500ms cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.5, 0.4, 1);
  transition-delay: 200ms;
}

.item-text-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.item-text-title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.item-text-category {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.item .item-button {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
}

.item .item-button:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #f7f7f5;
  color: #f7f7f5;
  transition: ease 0.4s;
}

#skills {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#skills .cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #f7f7f5;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#skills .card:first-of-type {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#skills .card {
  padding: 1rem;
}

#skills .skill-list h2 {
  color: #f43d56;
}

#skills i.fa-3x {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  color: #f43d56;
}

#skills ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#skills li {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

#skills h2 {
  padding: 1rem;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #f7f7f5;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.8;
  letter-spacing: 1.3px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #082449;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#logo {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-left: 4rem;
}

#main-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0 3rem;
  background-color: #f7f7f5;
}

#main-nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

#main-nav li {
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
}

#main-nav a {
  color: #082449;
  border: 1px solid #f43d56;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
}

#main-nav a:hover {
  background-color: #f43d56;
  color: #f7f7f5;
  transition: ease 0.4s;
}

#showcase {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  height: 60vh;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f7f7f5;
}

#showcase h1 {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

#showcase p {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

#showcase img {
  width: 100%;
}

#greeting {
  background-color: #f43d56;
  color: #f7f7f5;
   
}

#greeting h1 {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  font-size: 32px;
}

#greeting p {
  margin: 1rem auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
}

#greeting #more {
  display: none;
}

#greeting .btn-light {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#contact-a h3 {
  margin-top: 10%;
}

#contact-a .text-fields {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'name email' 'subject phone' 'message message';
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  margin: 3rem 0 2rem 0;
}

#contact-a .text-fields .name-input {
  grid-area: name;
}

#contact-a .text-fields .subject-input {
  grid-area: subject;
}

#contact-a .text-fields .email-input {
  grid-area: email;
}

#contact-a .text-fields .phone-input {
  grid-area: phone;
}

#contact-a .text-fields .message-input {
  grid-area: message;
  height: 100px;
}

#contact-a .text-fields .text-input {
  padding: 0.3rem 0.6rem;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#contact-a .contact-container .btn-dark {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
}

#contact-b .contact-info {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 4rem 0;
}

#main-footer {
  background: #082449;
  color: #f7f7f5;
  height: 5rem;
}

#main-footer .footer-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  height: 5rem;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

#main-footer .social .fab {
  color: #f7f7f5;
  margin-right: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-align: center;
}

#main-footer .social .fab:hover {
  background: #f43d56;
}

@media (max-width: 1300px) {
  #showcase {
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
  }
   
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #showcase {
    min-height: 50vh;
  }
  #showcase p {
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #showcase h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  #work-a .item-text-title {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
  #work-a .item-text-category {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }

  #greeting .container {
    padding: 0 2rem;
  }
  #skills .cards {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #skills .card:first-of-type {
    border-right: none;
  }
  #skills ul {
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
}


/*===================PHONES==================================

============================================================*/

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #main-nav {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  #main-nav #logo {
    margin: 1rem 0;
  }
  #main-nav li {
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-top: 2rem;
  }
  #showcase {
    height: 85vh;
  }
  #showcase p {
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #showcase img {
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #showcase h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }

  #greeting h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  #skills .cards {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  #skills .card:first-of-type {
    border-right: none;
  }
  #skills ul {
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
  #work-a .container {
    padding: 0 1rem;
  }
  #work-a .items {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    width: 100%;
    grid-row-gap: 0.5rem;
  }
  #work-a .items .item-image {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #work-a .items .item-text-category {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    margin-top: 1.8rem;
  }
  #work-a .items .item-text-title {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
  }
  #main-footer .footer-content {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    font-size: 0.6rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
  }
  #main-footer .social .fab {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    margin: 1rem 0;
  }
  #contact-a .text-fields {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 'name' 'email' 'phone' 'subject' 'message';
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    margin: 2rem 0;
  }
  #contact-b .contact-info {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-row-gap: 1rem;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-height: 500px) {
  #showcase {
    height: 85vh;
  }
  #showcase img {
    width: 250px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #showcase h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }

  #greeting h1 {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
  #skills .cards {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  #skills .card:first-of-type {
    border-right: none;
  }
  #skills ul {
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
  #work-a .items {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    width: 100%;
    grid-row-gap: 1rem;
  }
  #work-a .items .item-image {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #work-a .items .item-text-title {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    margin: 0.8rem 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="greeting" class="rellax" data-rellax-speed="3">
  <div class="container" data-rellax-speed="-1">
    <h1 class="rellax" data-rellax-speed="1" data-rellax-xs-speed="0">
      Hi, I'm Jon. Nice to meet you.
    </h1>
    <p class="rellax" data-rellax-speed="1" data-rellax-xs-speed="0">
      I am a recent graduate of the Borough of Manhattan Community College where I pursued a degree in Multimedia Programming with a specialization in Frontend Web Development and Graphic Design I offer an attention to detail, analysis, and problem solving
      that will serve me well as a Frontend Developer. I enjoy working across various programs and platforms from Sketch or XD to SASS/JS/REACT and NODE to name a few. In my recent internship at Interactive One, I was able to apply this skill set in the
      development of personalized landing pages and digital marketing campaigns on sites hosted on WordPress VIP.<span id="dots">...</span
          ><span id="more">
            I also find WordPress Development to be engaging as well, especially
            theme customization and incorporating raw coding techniques to
            create a unique end product. My specialties include: Prototyping in
            Adobe XD. Building in HTML/CSS, JavaScript and React. All aspects of
            the WordPress and Squarespace platforms. I have had the chance to
            work with Firebase creating an original Blog and also the P5.js
            library creating animated projects, games and data
            visualization.</span
          >
        </p>
        <button
          type="button"
          id="read"
          class="btn-light t-center"
          onclick="read()"
        >
          Read More
        </button>
      </div>
    </section>

<!-- Section Skills -->
    <section
      id="skills"
      class="t-center py-3 rellax"
      data-rellax-xs-speed="2"
      data-rellax-speed="1.5"
      data-rellax-tablet-speed="0"
    >
      <div class="container">
        <div class="cards">
          <div class="card">
            <div>
              <i class="fas fa-code fa-3x"></i>
              <h2>Frontend Developer</h2>
              <p>
                I aim for an original, clean and streamlined approach. I
                especially enjoy coding from scratch and exploring new
                techniques.
              </p>
              <div class="skill-list">
                <h2>My Languages:</h2>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fab fa-js"></i>
                    <p>javascript</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fab fa-react"></i>
                    <p>react</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fab fa-sass"></i>
                    <p>sass</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fab fa-node"></i>
                    <p>node.js</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fas fa-database"></i>
                    <p>firebase</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fas fa-file-code"></i>
                    <p>html5 / css3</p>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>

              <div class="skill-list">
                <h2>Developer Tools:</h2>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>
                    <p>VS-Code</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fab fa-bootstrap"></i>
                    <p>Bootstrap</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fab fa-codepen"></i>
                    <p>Codepen</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
                    <p>Github</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fab fa-wordpress"></i>
                    <p>WordPress</p>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div>
              <i class="fas fa-bezier-curve fa-3x"></i>
              <h2>Graphic Design</h2>
              <p>
                I value simple content structure, clean design patterns, and
                thoughtful interactions.
              </p>
              <div class="skill-list">
                <h2>What I like to design:</h2>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fab fa-sketch"></i>
                    <p>ux / ui</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fas fa-wifi"></i>
                    <p>web</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fas fa-mobile"></i>
                    <p>mobile</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fab fa-app-store-ios"></i>
                    <p>apps</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fas fa-bezier-curve"></i>
                    <p>logos</p>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>

              <div class="skill-list">
                <h2>Design Tools:</h2>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fas fa-align-center"></i>
                    <p>Sketch</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fab fa-figma"></i>
                    <p>Figma</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fab fa-adobe"></i>
                    <p>Adobe Suite</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <i class="fas fa-drafting-compass"></i>
                    <p>Draw</p>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Oh wow! massive fail on my part. Looks like I failed to run SASS when I tried that last week. Thanks so much for bringing that to my attention. It works great now.